# Difference between spine-tingling and spine-chilling?

Tags: word-usage, differences

I've learned the word 'spine-tingling' in an Oxford book. While when I look up that word in the Websters dictionary,there only comes out 'spine-chilling'. 
I perceived them as synonyms but no evidence suggests that. 
So what's the difference between them and what are their usage?

Comment: That would depend on the context. Some sexual positions are intriguing, others less so. All people are different, and no reaction can be predicted with any kind of certainty.

Comment: You had better try looking up what "tingling/tingle" and "chilling/chill" mean. They are all there.

Comment: @Ricky - Neither term has primarily sexual connotations.

Comment: @HotLicks: That's what THEY want you to think. In accordance with the prophecy.

Comment: They mean essentially the same thing -- scary.  "Spine-tingling" is by far the more common, in the US, but "spine-chilling" might be used for, eg, a zombie movie that leaves one feeling cold and "dead" vs overly stimulated.

Comment: "It sends chills up and down my spine" and "It sends tingles to my fingertips" are expressions (in US) that are not really interchangeable ["It sends chills to my fingertips" would sound awkward]. Frequently used to describe sensations of pleasure (although sometimes preceded by "happy" to distinguish from scary).

Comment: Generally it's usually **bone**-chilling and spine-tingling. But people get confused fairly often.

Answer (score 1):

There is a picture in today's Otago Daily Times of a man running whilst he is ablaze from an explosion, and the caption reads, " The spine-tingling image of a man running while engulfed in flames ", etc.. This, to me, should be described as ' spine-chilling' rather than tingling, because of the horror and life threatening aspect. Spine tingling is a different experience altogether, I think anyway.

Comment: Just plain **chilling** would ordinarily be the best choice for something unspeakably horrifying -- but for fires it would be unfortunately ludicrous.

Answer (score 0):

According to *A Dictionary of Confusable Phrases: More than 10,000 Idioms and Collocations*:

Something **spine-[chilling](https://books.google.com/books?id=LAKQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=spine%20tingling%20vs%20spine%20chilling&source=bl&ots=IR3prG2JKJ&sig=RH-g8RXdA3-LZOjFhvsXOSTar7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCyPrA24PbAhUk_IMKHa-oBQQQ6AEIrQEwEw#v=onepage&q=spine%20tingling%20vs%20spine%20chilling&f=false)** is *terrifying*, whereas something **spine-[tingling](https://books.google.com/books?id=LAKQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=spine%20tingling%20vs%20spine%20chilling&source=bl&ots=IR3prG2JKJ&sig=RH-g8RXdA3-LZOjFhvsXOSTar7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCyPrA24PbAhUk_IMKHa-oBQQQ6AEIrQEwEw#v=onepage&q=spine%20tingling%20vs%20spine%20chilling&f=false)** is *exciting*.